# Enable TLSv1.1 on httpd 2.4.56 running on Docker

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, docker, openssl, alpine

I am trying to modernize the infrastructure of a HTTP web service. I want to update the web server to something more recent and secure, but I have to maintain compatibility with some legacy devices in the field that are unable to connect using TLSv1.2.

The web server I am using is httpd version 2.4.56 running on a Docker container with Alpine Linux (for reference the image is [httpd:2.4.56-alpine3.17](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/httpd/2.4.56-alpine3.17/images/sha256-e9068055aad2e2ecf0d3cada9d017dc3770f1a7521cf3d6a3aae2e587873f3b2?context=explore)).

I tried enabling TLSv1.1 ciphers changing the default `httpd-ssl.conf` file with this lines:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:@SECLEVEL=1
SSLProxyCipherSuite ALL:@SECLEVEL=1
```

The `SSLProtocol` and `SSLProxyProtocol` directives are both set to `all -SSLv3`.

After that I changed `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` by adding at the top

```
openssl_conf = default_conf
```

and

```
[default_conf]
ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]
system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.1
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1

[openssl_init]
providers = provider_sect
```

after the `[ new_oids ]` section.

To test the result I used the command `nmap -script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 9443 localhost` and obtained the following result:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
9443/tcp open  tungsten-https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM_8 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CCM (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_ARIA_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_ARIA_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|   TLSv1.3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|     cipher preference: server
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.41 seconds
```

so, clearly I am missing something, as I expected some TLSv1.1 ciphers to show up.

I also tried inserting some syntax errors to see if the `openssl.cnf` file is read correctly and it seems that the configuration is ignored even if i can find it browsing the container filesystem.

Comment: It feels quite odd to ask about setting something in httpd and not show one bit of httpd configuration. Could you please update your question and show the appropiate bits? At the very least you should have a directive such as `SSLProtocol all -TLSv1`.

Comment: I tried to attach httpd-ssl.conf and openssl.cnf but the question was getting flagged as spam.
I previously asked the [same question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743303/enable-tlsv1-1-on-httpd-2-4-56-running-on-docker), there I managed to include the full configuration.
The only changes I made from the default configuration are the ones listed on the first part of the question.
I am aware of the `SSLProtocol all -TLSv1` directive and now I included it in my configuration in place of `all -SSLv3`

Comment: I tried your SSLCIpherSuite and my openssl gave me an error, try a more sane list, for example one similar to the one in mozilla ssl generator including inferior ciphers: `SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA`

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried your configuration and the output of the `nmap` command now has a more compact list of ciphers, but it still has only TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3.
Can this be a problem of the OpenSSL version? In the logs I see `[Thu Mar 30 08:08:03.000603 2023] [ssl:info] [pid 1:tid 139702950845256] AH01876: mod_ssl/2.4.56 compiled against Server: Apache/2.4.56, Library: OpenSSL/3.0.8`, maybe 3.0.8 does not support older ciphers, but I can't find any information online regarding this

Comment: For reference this is the ciphers list I get as output, maybe it can be helpful
`TLSv1.2:
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
TLSv1.3:
    TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (ecdh_x25519) - A
    TLS_AKE_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
    TLS_AKE_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A`

Comment: That's probably it, I haven´t used OpenSSL 3.x so I can't tell, but you can check it by yourself with this command: `openssl ciphers -v 'ALL' `

Comment: The Alpine Linux container I was using did not have the openssl command, after I switched to the `2.4.56-bullseye` image and after porting the modifications I did to the Alpine version, the container started accepting TLSv1.1 ciphers. I guess the openssl 3.0.8 configuration has something different form the 1.1.1 that the Bullseye container uses, because on a Ubuntu 22.04 with openssl 3.0.2 I see a bunch of TLSv1 ciphers.
@DanielFerradal thanks for the help, I'll keep the question open if someone that knows how to enable TLSv1.1 on the specific Alpine Linux version stumbles upon it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working following the suggestions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75743303/enable-tlsv1-1-on-httpd-2-4-56-running-on-docker).

To sum it up it works by changing `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1` to `CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0` in the `openssl.cnf` file when using openssl version 3.

I suggest to expose only what is necessary for the given use case, as an example I exposed only TLSv1.1 using the `MinProtocol` directive on `openssl.cnf`.